# How to get the new child element reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I've a **list with DOM elements** that I **map** in the render function. Now, when I click a button I can add a new element, and I've a function that is working to do that. I push the element in the list in this way:

```
this.state.addedText.push(
    <div className="editable" id={idDiv} onChange={(e) => this._changeText(e)} contentEditable style={{display: "block", position: "absolute", fontWeight: "bold", backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)", wordWrap: "break-word", textAlign: "center", width: "100%", color: "white", top: "0px", borderTop: "1px solid white", borderBottom: "1px solid white"}}>
       {this.state.textDivAdded[nextItem]}
    </div>
 );
```

and then I call the **forceUpdate**. Now, the id of element is something like "editable_#" where # is the position in the array (so something like editable_1, editable_2 and so on..).

If, below the forceUpdate, I put `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("editable"))` I can see the new element, but I can't get it. If I write `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("editable"))[0]` I've "**undefined**".

This is how I render the list:

```
{this.state.addedText.length > 0 && this.state.addedText.map(v => {
  return (
      <Draggable defaultPosition={{x: 0, y: 0}} enableUserSelectHack={false} axis="both" bounds="parent">
         {v}
      </Draggable>
  )
})}
```

As you can see the div that I add is "**contentEditable**", so I can change the text of it, and I need to add an eventlistener to get the "onChange", but I don't know how to get this element after the rendering, and also I need to focus it when I add it to the DOM.

Obiously, when I add a second element I can get the previous item added.

Some idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about rethinking your design, 
the state would hold the value of the divs:

```
this.state = {
   texts: [];
}

...

{this.state.texts.length && this.state.texts.map((v,i) => {
  return (
      <Draggable key={i} ...>
         <div className="editable" onChange={(e) => this._changeText(i,e)} contentEditable ...>
          {v}
         </div>
      </Draggable>
  )
})}
```

To add a text:

```
this.setState({
   texts: [...this.state.texts, 'whatever, coming from an array?']
});
```

To change text:

```
_changeText(i,e) {
   this.setState({
      texts: this.state.texts.map((t,j), => i == j ? e.target.value : t)
   });
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is ok for the changing text.. But how can I get the element when I add it after the forceUpdate()..

Comment: then you would have to keep a ref (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)
but that is the part where you may have to change your design... With this method, you don't need force update nor anything more... Why do you need to get the element ? Is it a bit anti-pattern in React...

Comment: Ok, I created an array **refText** and I add the elements' refs here in this way: `ref={(e) => this.refText[i] = e}` (this in the map of .texts state). When I click the button to add an element, and after that I updated my state texts I did a `console.log(this.refText, this.refText[0])`, and [this is](https://i.gyazo.com/4cdc55db411fb4b93d096f11b0817c99.png) what I have. As you can see the element at position 0 is "undefined" and not a DOM element..

Comment: If I insert a setTimeout of 100ms and then I check for the element, it works.. there is a way to avoid a setTimeout?

Comment: The only way I see is to use the componentdidupdate to check the existence. Would that fit your design?

Comment: Okay, no I tried componentdidupdate, but it is useless in this case..! I'll leave a setTimeout of 100ms, I think this is not a big problem!

Comment: Cool, you may accept the answer then, good luck for the rest !